# Why does QTextEdit sometimes emit textChanged too many times on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

I'm using PyQT5 and Python 3.8.  I have exactly the same code running on Ubuntu 20.04 and on Windows 10, with the same dependencies installed from the same requirements.txt file using pip, the contents of which are:

```
mistune==0.8.4
PyQt5==5.15.0
PyQt5-sip==12.8.0
PyQt5-stubs==5.14.2.2
```

For some reason, when I run my app on Ubuntu, the second time the textChanged signal should be emitted, it emits twice.

For example, the expected behavior is this:

```
Action triggered first time:
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered second time:
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered third time:
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered fourth time:
    textChanged signal emitted

...
```

And this is indeed what happens on Windows.  There is no duplicate signal emission.  But on Ubuntu, I get this:

```
Action triggered first time:
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered second time:
    textChanged signal emitted
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered third time:
    textChanged signal emitted

Action triggered fourth time:
    textChanged signal emitted

...
```

Again, same code from the same repository, same dependencies installed from pip.  The one difference in setup that I'm aware of is that Ubuntu wouldn't run the app at all unless I also installed PyQT5 with APT instead of pip3, using `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5`, because for some reason pip wasn't including an xcb file that is needed for Qt to work on Ubuntu.

Only on the second time the signal should be emitted have I seen it emitted twice.  Not on any other occasion.  But it consistently misbehaves in this way.

I am baffled.  As far as the actual impact on my app, it's fine in practice; it just sets an unsaved changes flag erroneously the one time, because the unwanted signal emission happens outside of another flag.  But if possible I'd really like to get to the bottom of this, in case it has other consequences I'm not seeing, or in case it proves problematic for some other app down the road.

---

Edited for minimum reproducible example.  Making this helped me narrow it down, so thanks for prodding me not to be so lazy.  What appears to be happening is that, for some reason, if the `QTextEdit` is put in a read only state, and then toggled *out* of the read only state, and then focus is set, a `textChanged` signal is emitted for some reason, but only *once*.  Further toggling of the read only state and focus changes to the `QTextEdit` do not trigger this extra signal emission.

This does not happen on Windows, as is the expected behavior.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFrame, QGridLayout

TextChangedCounter = 0

def StartApp():
    AppInst = QApplication(sys.argv)

    def TextChanged():
        global TextChangedCounter
        TextChangedCounter += 1
        print("textChanged emitted", TextChangedCounter, "times.")

    def ToggleReadOnly():
        TextEdit.setReadOnly(not TextEdit.isReadOnly())
        if not TextEdit.isReadOnly():
            TextEdit.setFocus()

    MainWindow = QMainWindow()

    Frame = QFrame()

    TextEdit = QTextEdit()
    TextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
    TextEdit.textChanged.connect(TextChanged)

    ToggleButton = QPushButton("Toggle Read Only")
    ToggleButton.clicked.connect(ToggleReadOnly)

    Layout = QGridLayout()
    Layout.addWidget(TextEdit)
    Layout.addWidget(ToggleButton)
    Frame.setLayout(Layout)

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(Frame)

    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(AppInst.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    StartApp()
```

So to be clear:  The expected behavior, which occurs correctly on Windows 10, is that clicking the button labeled "Toggle Read Only" should *not* print "textChanged emitted 1 times."  However, on Ubuntu 20.04, this message is printed by clicking the button, but *only* the first time.

---

Edited to add something else:  Apparently setting the focus on the QTextEdit before toggling the read only state delays this extra signal emission until you actually type something in the QTextEdit, as in the altered function below.  But...  *why*?

```
def ToggleReadOnly():
    if TextEdit.isReadOnly():
        TextEdit.setFocus()
    TextEdit.setReadOnly(not TextEdit.isReadOnly())
    if not TextEdit.isReadOnly():
        TextEdit.setFocus()
```

---

Edited to add results of suggestion in comments.  Removing the APT installation of `python3-pyqt5` and reinstalling the pip version in the venv results in the following output, which is exactly what caused me to install the APT version originally:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Two things result in the GUI running at all:

1. Installing the APT version of PyQT5 (which is apparently 5.14.1) with `sudo install python3-pyqt5` along with the pip version 5.15.0 in the venv.  I can then `sudo apt remove python3-pyqt5` and the GUI still works, but once I `sudo apt autoremove` it stops working again.
2. Apparently (and this is new to me in the last ten minutes) I can get away with running *just* PyQT5 version 5.14.1 in the venv through pip, without installing the APT version at all (though it looks as though Ubuntu 20.04 has a pre-installed version that is also 5.14.1).

But neither set of installed dependencies resolves the question, because the extra signal emission is present in both.

---

Edit for response to quoted comment:

> do the following and tell me what you get in each step: 1) remove python3-pyqt5

Output:

```
snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~$ sudo apt remove python3-pyqt5
[sudo] password for snackhole: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5network5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5test5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 python3-sip qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qttranslations5-l10n
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-pyqt5
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 16.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216860 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3-pyqt5 (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1) ...
snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5network5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5test5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 python3-sip qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qttranslations5-l10n
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 53.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216792 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5designer5:amd64 (5.12.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.12.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5test5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5help5:amd64 (5.12.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing python3-sip (4.19.21+dfsg-1build1) ...
Removing qttranslations5-l10n (5.12.8-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5network5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-xinput0:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdouble-conversion3:amd64 (3.1.5-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpcre2-16-0:amd64 (10.34-7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~$
```

---

> 2. create a virtualenv and activate it

Done, in a new directory, though I'm used to creating virtual environments through PyCharm, so I had to run `sudo apt install python3-venv` first.

---

> 3. update pip and install PyQt5: python -m pip install --upgrade pip and python -m pip install pyqt5.

Output:

```
(venv) snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~/Documents/Test$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
Successfully installed pip-20.1.1
(venv) snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~/Documents/Test$ python3 -m pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0-5.15.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (76.6 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.8.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (293 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip, pyqt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-sip-12.8.0 pyqt5-5.15.0
```

---

> 4. run your script with the following command QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_script.py – eyllanesc

Output:

```
(venv) snackhole@UbuntuMachine:~/Documents/Test$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python3 QTextEditBug.py
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/snackhole/Documents/Test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

Edit:  Running `sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0` as suggested by @eyllanesc bypasses the need for an APT install of `python3-pyqt5`, which is great (legitimately, not being sarcastic!), but unfortunately does not actually solve the issue that prompted my question:  The test app, run in a venv with PyQT5 installed (whether 5.15.0 or 5.14.1), still emits this baffling single extra signal when focus is given to the `QTextEdit` after it has been set to read only and then toggled back to editable.

---

Edit:  Bizarrely, it turns out that the test app also fires *five* `textChanged` signals when you alt tab away.  Pressing alt on its own produces one signal, and then when the window loses focus it produces four more...   none of which occurs on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you testing this on a basic QTextEdit based program? What is the text you're typing?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Example edited in.

Comment: And found an inexplicable partial workaround...

Comment: @Snackhole I do not reproduce the problem in arch linux (I use a virtualenv installing pyqt5 via pip), could you indicate how you have installed pyqt5. Please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc I have installed it in a venv with pip as well, on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.  However, it won't run on my Ubuntu 20.04 without also installing it system-wide using `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5` due to a missing or unreadable xcb file.

Comment: @Snackhole  mmm, uninstall that package(`python3-pyqt5`) and install pyqt5 with pip again(python -m pip install pyqt5), the xcb problem should already be solved

Comment: @eyllanesc Please see updated question.

Comment: @Snackhole do the following and tell me what you get in each step: 1) remove python3-pyqt5, 2) create a virtualenv and activate it, 3) update pip and install PyQt5: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`  and `python -m pip install pyqt5`. 4) run your script with the following command `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_script.py`

Comment: @eyllanesc See updated question again!

Comment: execute `sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0 `

Comment: @eyllanesc Updated question.